# How to align statements around a particular word or token?

Tags: alignment, plugin-tabular

I want to align my statements around a particular word or token.

Example:

```
import React          from 'react';
import { browserHistory, Router, Route } from 'react-router';
import Main           from './components/main';
```

In this case, I want my statements to be aligned around `from` word.

Like this

```
import React                             from 'react';
import { browserHistory, Router, Route } from 'react-router';
import Main                              from './components/main';
```

I have installed a plugin called `tabular` but I don't know how to align around a word. I can align around `=` or any other token but not around a word.

Comment: You should also see [vim-easy-align](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align). It provides an operator for aligning, which makes it possible to align using motions and text objects as targets. It also provides a live and interactive align operation which shows how the alignment will look for the provided options in realtime, `LiveEasyAlign`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Tabular plugin works with regular expressions. So, you can give a word or a pattern, not just a single character.

```
:Tabularize /from/
```

will align in the way you wanted.

You can find a great tutorial about [Tabular on Vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/aligning-text-with-tabular-vim/).