# Tabularizing all Commas after `EST[`?

Tags: regular-expression, plugin-tabular

How do tabularize all commas after instances of `EST[` so that text like

```
Item 1 //EST[5555m, 6666m]
Item 2 //EST[1m, 300m]
```

gets transformed into something like:

```
Item 1 //EST[5555m , 6666m]
Item 2 //EST[1m    , 300m]
```

The best starting command I know is `:Tabularize \,`, but it's not quite specific enough because it tabularizes all commas and not just those proceeding `EST[`.

Comment: It seems to me that this is basically the same as your other question: "How do I use :Tabular only for delimiters after a certain pattern?", so I've marked it as a duplicate for now. If it's not a duplicate then let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You could try installing the [tabular plugin](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular/blob/master/README.md).  It looks like it will take a regular expression and tabularize the contents of your file.
There are examples in the documentation such as:

```
abc,def,ghi
a,b
a,b,c
```

After running `:Tabularize /,/r1c1l0`:

```
abc , def, ghi
  a , b
  a , b  ,  c
```

and since you have an accessible expression of the comma after `EST[` it looks like a good fit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer; however, I'm having trouble knowing what expression to place after `:Tabularize /`.

Comment: How about `:Tabularize /EST[.*,/`  This would look for EST[_any characters_,  I meant to add the link to the Tabularize screencast from this answer https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/8105/how-to-align-statements-around-a-particular-word-or-token/8106#8106 about using regular expressions with Tabularize.