# Automatic format: how to insert needed amount of spaces for vertical aligning?

Tags: formatting, filetype-html

Given code:

```
<option id='Nicole' data-language='en-AU'>Australian English - female - Nicole</option>
<option id='Russell' data-language='en-AU'>Australian English - female - Russell</option>
<option id='Ricardo' data-language='pt-BR'>Brazilian Portuguese - female - Ricardo</option>
<option id='Vitoria' data-language='pt-BR'>Brazilian Portuguese - female - Vitória</option>
<option id='Amy' data-language='en-GB'>British English - female - Amy</option>
<option id='Brian' data-language='en-GB'>British English - female - Brian</option>
<option id='Emma' data-language='en-GB'>British English - female - Emma</option>
<option id='Chantal' data-language='fr-CA'>Canadian French - female - Chantal</option>
<option id='Conchita' data-language='es-ES'>Castilian Spanish - female - Conchita</option>
<option id='Enrique' data-language='es-ES'>Castilian Spanish - female - Enrique</option>
<option id='Mads' data-language='da-DK'>Danish - female - Mads</option>
<option id='Naja' data-language='da-DK'>Danish - female - Naja</option>
<option id='Lotte' data-language='nl-NL'>Dutch - female - Lotte</option>
<option id='Ruben' data-language='nl-NL'>Dutch - female - Ruben</option>
<option id='Celine' data-language='fr-FR'>French - female - Céline</option>
<option id='Lea' data-language='fr-FR'>French - female - Léa</option>
<option id='Mathieu' data-language='fr-FR'>French - female - Mathieu</option>
<option id='Hans' data-language='de-DE'>German - female - Hans</option>
<option id='Marlene' data-language='de-DE'>German - female - Marlene</option>
<option id='Vicki' data-language='de-DE'>German - female - Vicki</option>
<option id='Dora' data-language='is-IS'>Icelandic - female - Dóra</option>
<option id='Karl' data-language='is-IS'>Icelandic - female - Karl</option>
<option id='Aditi' data-language='en-IN'>Indian English - female - Aditi</option>
<option id='Raveena' data-language='en-IN'>Indian English - female - Raveena</option>
<option id='Carla' data-language='it-IT'>Italian - female - Carla</option>
<option id='Giorgio' data-language='it-IT'>Italian - female - Giorgio</option>
<option id='Mizuki' data-language='ja-JP'>Japanese - female - Mizuki</option>
<option id='Takumi' data-language='ja-JP'>Japanese - female - Takumi</option>
<option id='Seoyeon' data-language='ko-KR'>Korean - female - Seoyeon</option>
<option id='Liv' data-language='nb-NO'>Norwegian - female - Liv</option>
<option id='Ewa' data-language='pl-PL'>Polish - female - Ewa</option>
<option id='Jacek' data-language='pl-PL'>Polish - female - Jacek</option>
<option id='Jan' data-language='pl-PL'>Polish - female - Jan</option>
<option id='Maja' data-language='pl-PL'>Polish - female - Maja</option>
<option id='Cristiano' data-language='pt-PT'>Portuguese - female - Cristiano</option>
<option id='Ines' data-language='pt-PT'>Portuguese - female - Inês</option>
<option id='Carmen' data-language='ro-RO'>Romanian - female - Carmen</option>
<option id='Maxim' data-language='ru-RU'>Russian - female - Maxim</option>
<option id='Tatyana' data-language='ru-RU'>Russian - female - Tatyana</option>
<option id='Astrid' data-language='sv-SE'>Swedish - female - Astrid</option>
<option id='Filiz' data-language='tr-TR'>Turkish - female - Filiz</option>
<option id='Ivy' data-language='en-US'>US English - female - Ivy</option>
<option id='Joanna' data-language='en-US' selected>US English - female - Joanna</option>
<option id='Joey' data-language='en-US'>US English - female - Joey</option>
<option id='Justin' data-language='en-US'>US English - female - Justin</option>
<option id='Kendra' data-language='en-US'>US English - female - Kendra</option>
<option id='Kimberly' data-language='en-US'>US English - female - Kimberly</option>
<option id='Matthew' data-language='en-US'>US English - female - Matthew</option>
<option id='Salli' data-language='en-US'>US English - female - Salli</option>
<option id='Miguel' data-language='es-US'>US Spanish - female - Miguel</option>
<option id='Penelope' data-language='es-US'>US Spanish - female - Penélope</option>
<option id='Gwyneth' data-language='cy-GB'>Welsh - female - Gwyneth</option>
<option id='Geraint' data-language='en-GB-WLS'>Welsh English - female - Geraint</option>
```

How to get this?
[image: vim html formatting]

Comment: We have a duplicate question [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/594/1841) and another one recommending Tabular [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/8105/1841) which would be my choice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [Tabular plugin](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular).

You're going to need some kind of plugin for this. The tools Vim has natively are not powerful enough by themselves and not really powerful enough to create simple mappings. So you'll need some kind of scripting.